# Avoid using for loop in np.array operations. Python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy

I have these two arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 10, 20])
b = np.array([20, 30, 40, 50])
```

I'd like to add both in the following way:

```
for i in range (len(a)):
   for j in range(len(b)):
      c = a[i] + b[j]
      d = delta(c, dr)
```

As you see for each iteration I get a value `c` which I pass through a function `delta` (see note at the end of the post).
The thing is that I want to avoid slow Python "for" loops when the arrays are huge.

One thing I could do would be:

```
c = np.ravel(a(-1, 1) + b)
```

Which is much much faster. The problem is that now `c` is an array, and again I would have to go throw it using a for loop. 
So, do you have any idea on how I could do this without using a for loop at all.

NOTE: `delta` is a function I define in the following way:

```
def delta(r,dr):
   if r >= 0.5*dr and r <= 1.5*dr:
     delta = (5-3*abs(r)/dr-np.sqrt(-3*(1-abs(r)/dr)**2+1))/(6*dr)
   elif r <= 0.5*dr:
     delta = (1+np.sqrt(-3*(r/dr)**2+1))/(3*dr)
   else:
     delta = 0
   return delta
```

Comment: Is `function` a suitable NumPy `ufunc`, or a Python function? In the former case, you might be able to optimize; in the latter, you wouldn't.

Comment: @inetphantom Edited.

Comment: Your `delta` function takes two variables, not one as in the `for` loop.  Also, it doesn't return anything.  Did you intend to return the `delta` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ravel` is a good idea.  Note that you could also use simple [array broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) (`a[:, np.newaxis] + b[np.newaxis, :]`).

For your `function`, you can improve this a lot because it is composed of only three particular cases.  Probably the best approach is to use masking for each of those three sections.

You're starting with:

```
def delta(r,dr):
   if r >= 0.5*dr and r <= 1.5*dr:
     delta = (5-3*abs(r)/dr-np.sqrt(-3*(1-abs(r)/dr)**2+1))/(6*dr)
   elif r <= 0.5*dr:
     delta = (1+np.sqrt(-3*(r/dr)**2+1))/(3*dr)
   else:
     delta = 0
```

A common alternative approach would be something like:

```
def delta(r, dr):
    res = np.zeros_like(r)
    ma = (r >= 0.5*dr) & (r <= 1.5*dr)  # Create first mask
    res[ma] = (5-3*np.abs(r[ma])/dr[ma]-np.sqrt(-3*(1-np.abs(r[ma])/dr[ma])**2+1))/(6*dr[ma])
    ma = (r <= 0.5*dr)    # Create second mask
    res[ma] = (1+np.sqrt(-3*(r[ma]/dr[ma])**2+1))/(3*dr[ma])
    return res
```

Initializing to zeros handles the final `else` case.  Also I'm assuming `np.abs` is faster than `abs` --- but I'm not actually sure...

---

Edit: *for **sparse** matrices*

The same basic idea should apply, but perhaps instead of using a boolean masking array, using the valid indices themselves would be better... e.g. something like:

```
res = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(np.shape(r))
ma = np.where((r >= 0.5*dr) & (r <= 1.5*dr))  # Create first mask
res[ma] = ...
```

Comment: NIce.  I was just writing a nearly identical answer!

Comment: BTW: `and` doesn't work between `bool` arrays.  You'll need to use `&`.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix That´s just what I needed, it is much faster for huge matrix. However the reason of doing it one by one using a for-loop was to create 3 vector one with the result other with i and other with k and then create a coo-matrix, since most of the elements are zero. Now I have a dense matrix. Any ideas to create a coo_matrix and not write thousands of elements with value zero?
Thanks.

Comment: @FernandoBastosGarcía hmm, interesting, honestly I've never used sparse matrices :/  but I've added an edit with what I assume should work...  Let me know!

Comment: I think you should post a separate sparse matrix question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same answer as DilithiumMatrix, but using logical functions that numpy accepts to generate the masks.

```
import numpy as np
def delta(r, dr):
    res = np.zeros(r.shape)
    mask1 = (r >= 0.5*dr) & (r <= 1.5*dr)
    res[mask1] = \
        (5-3*np.abs(r[mask1])/dr \
        - np.sqrt(-3*(1-np.abs(r[mask1])/dr)**2+1)) \
         /(6*dr)
    mask2 = np.logical_not(mask1) & (r <= 0.5*dr)
    res[mask2] = (1+np.sqrt(-3*(r[mask2]/dr)**2+1))/(3*dr)
    return res
```

Comment: please check the comment I write in DilithiumMatrix answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your two arrays (a and b) are not enormous, you could do something like this:

```
import itertools
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
b = numpy.array([4,5,6])
c = numpy.sum(list(itertools.product(a, b), 1)
def func(x, y):
    return x*y
numpy.vectorize(func)(c, 10)
```

Note that with large arrays, this simply won't work - you'll have `n**2` elements in `c`, which means that even for smallish-seeming pairs of arrays, you'll use enormous amounts of memory. For 2 arrays with 100,000 elements each, total memory required will be in the range of 74 GB.

Comment: You don't need the `itertools.product` to implement a vectorized product.  Also, your `func` doesn't implement the OP's `function`.